# What are the benefits of a solenoid over a relay in an electric cart?

Tags: relay, dc-motor, solid-state-relay, solenoid

I was looking over the wiring diagram of a [Electric Golf Cart](http://golftechs.us/Manuals/EZ%20GO/48%20Volt%20TXT/48V%20TXT%20Service%20Manual.pdf) and noticed the use of a solenoid. The initial literature I found suggest that the solenoid is only engaged when the key is in the engaged position and the pedal is depressed.

[image: golf cart wiring diagram]

So my question is: wouldn't a simple relay suffice? Is the solenoid doing more than just being in an off/on position or just better than a simple relay for this use-case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few relays in cars etc are up to 50A and those are special such as for heater plugs etc. More common is 30A.

A solenoid is used for starters at 300A to over 1000A so that is why it is used in this case - due to the current flow that has to be controlled.

Answer (score 2):

In automotive electrical circuits, I believe a solenoid is a high current relay also known as a contactor. In other contexts, a solenoid is a mechanical actuator that might operate a valve or do some other mechnical work that requires only a short linear thrusting or pulling motion.

In the application described in the question, a high-current relay is required. That could be purchased as a contactor from an electrical supply house, but one with the proper rating may be more likely called a solenoid.